# Alternative proof of IVT (I've nearly done it, one step I can't write down properly but is fine)

Tags: real-analysis

Note: This is different because every proof I have seen (including the one I learnt) uses bisection and nested intervals - I don't claim to be the first or anything but it seems to not be the conventional proof.

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Suppose that $f(a)\ne f(b)$ then for $v$ strictly between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ $\exists c\in(a,b):f(c)=v$

Proof (for $f(a)<v<f(b)$ - otherwise $\times-1, still continuous)

Consider the set $A=\{x\in[a,b]|f(x)\le v\}$, note $a\in A$ and it is bounded above by $b\ \implies$ has a least upper bound ($\sup$)

Let $c=\sup(A)$

There exists $x_n\in A$ with $x_n\rightarrow c$ (by axiom of completness - I'd like more info on this, rather than just "trust me lowly undergraduate, it exists"). By the continuity of $f$

$f(x_n)\rightarrow f(c)$, we know $f(x_n)\le v$ by definition.

$\implies f(c)\le v$ (see note at bottom this is iffy, true, but iffy - should be obvious "trivial" - why?)

If we suppose $f(c)<v$, let $g(x)=v-f(x)$ then we are saying $g(c)>0$, as $g$ is continuous (addition, or rather subtraction of cont functions) we know:

$\exists\delta>0:|x-c|<\delta\implies|g(x)-g(c)|<\frac{g(c)}{2}\iff\frac{g(c)}{2}<g(x)<\frac{3g(c)}{2}$
notice $0<\frac{g(c)}{2}<g(x)=v-f(x)$ so $f(x)<v$
 whenever $|x-c|<\delta\iff c-\delta<x<c+\delta$

So $x=c+\frac{\delta}{2}\implies f(x)<v$ - a contradiction (as $x>c$ that $c$ is een an upper bound).

So $f(c)\ge v$, if we use the iffy $f(c)\le v$ then $f(c)=v$

This completes the proof.

### Iffy part

The bad part is $f(x_n)\le v\implies f(c)\le v$. We know $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(c)$, this means
$\forall\epsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:n>N\implies|f(x_n)-f(c)|<\epsilon$
$\iff f(c)-\epsilon<f(x_n)<f(c)+\epsilon$ - taking just the right part:
$\implies f(c)-\epsilon<f(x_n)\le v$ by definition
$\implies f(c)-\epsilon< v\implies f(c)<\epsilon+v$

(some stuff here re-written then removed 3 times, this is where I go in circles)

Comment: Now set $ϵ=1/n$ and consider the inequality in the limit $n\to\infty$.